# Find an expression, which is the and of clauses, equivalent to $( p \lor q) \to r$ .

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

I have to do the following problem :

Find an expression, which is the and of clauses, equivalent
to $( p \lor q) \to r$.

But I don't understand what ''which is the and of clauses'' means.

(I am doing the class in french but the book is in English, so maybe I've seen this expression in french but never translated to English)

Comment: I think they mean a product of sums.

Comment: Yes, conjunctive normal form https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form

Comment: Thanks guys! :)

Comment: I feel that it must be noted that "the and of clauses" is terrible English; no logician says that. The correct terminology, as others had pointed out, is "conjunctive normal form". In other words, the book is **not** in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *clause* is a disjunction of literals, and a *literal* is an atomic formula or its negation.

So, your exercise asks for a conjunction of clauses, also known as [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form), that is logically equivalent to $(p \lor q) \to r$. Using well-known [logical equivalences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence), you get:

\begin{align}
(p \lor q) \to r &\equiv \lnot (p \lor q) \lor r &\text{by decomposition of $\to$} \\
&\equiv (\lnot p \land \lnot q) \lor r &\text{by De Morgan law}  \\
&\equiv (\lnot p \lor r) \land (\lnot q \lor r) &\text{by distributivity of $\lor$ over $\land$}
\end{align}

where $(\lnot p \lor r) \land (\lnot q \lor r)$ is the formula you are looking for because it is a conjunctive normal form (since it is a conjunction of the literals $\lnot p \lor r$ and $\lnot q \lor r$) and it is logically equivalent to $(p \lor q) \to r$ (since it is obtained by substitution of logically equivalent sub-formulas).